# Apache + Python : Serving binairy files

Tags: python, apache

I have an Apache server with python cgi (Python3). A client start a get request to get a virtual file, and I need to give him back the good one regarding his user-agent. I was able to do it with text files but when I try to serve back binairies files like images (.jpg) or .zip, the downloaded file seems corrupted.

When I parse it I can see `b'\x00\x....'` so I think the byte conversion went wrong somewhere.

I have tried with `sys.stdout.write` but it expects a str not bytes. I have tried also to "play" with the headers by changing the content type for example but it is not working.

```
reqFile = open(filePath,'rb')
content = reqFile.read()
print("Content-Type:image/jpg")
print("Accept-Rangers:byte")
print("Content-Length:"+str(len(content))
print()
print (content)
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found that print() insert '\n' character and other stuff. So, for binairies file, I recommend to use sys.stdout.

```
    file = open(filePath, "rb")
    content = file.read()
    length = len(content)
    file.close()

    print("Content-type:application/x-download")
    print("Content-length:%d" % length)
    print()

    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(content)
```

Don't forget to do sys.stdout.flush() in order to have a clean output.